# JQuery Processes timeline

Tags: jquery, timeline

I'm looking for processes timeline. CSS or JQuery.

In timeline i want to show processes such as Cronjobs, XML import, data export and so on.
Timeline should have start time, length and title ( maybe group ).
Some processes can be launched twice per hour. Some can be launched once per month.

Mission of the timeline - ability to see which spots of time is not used by the processes.

I have searched a lot for something like this, but no success.
Something similar i found here:
http://stoicloofah.github.io/chronoline.js/
But it doesn't gives ability to show data with second accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any script which shows with second accuracy. So i have used the [chronoline.js](http://stoicloofah.github.io/chronoline.js/) script. My solution for seconds problem was: to add calculated length into 'title', so I could see how long process lasted while hovering over timeline object.

Code:

```
'start': new Date(<?php echo date("Y,m,d,H,i,s",$item['start_time']) ?>),
'end': new Date(<?php echo date("Y,m,d,H,i,s",$item['finish_time']) ?>),
'content': '<div class="content_title_b" title="<?php echo $item['title'];?> - <?php echo $item['length'];?> sec."><?php echo $item['title'];?></div>'
```

The script is pretty simple and has some nice "features".

- Zooms in/zooms out while scrolling over timeline;
- Has it own css, which is easy editable.

Let me know if you found something better. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the only solution you've found, бро?

Comment: Yep. Have any better ideas? бро.

Comment: I've researched some other libs, but in the end created my own solution with tables and colspans.

Comment: In sum, my result has table too, but on top I display the timeline.

Comment: Yeap, seem that the perferct solution is to fron jQuery.Gantt and make minimum scale - seconds.